# How to call an embedded struct method of an object passed as interface?

Tags: go, struct, interface

My scenario requires the user to embed a base struct and implement an interface.
Then, an instance of that struct should be passed to a function. The function needs to call a method of the base struct. This fails

```
// Given base struct and interface

type Interface interface {
    Do()
}

type BaseStruct struct {
    i int
    s string
}

func (*b BaseStruct) Stuff() {}

// The user needs to create a struct that embeds BaseStruct and to implement Interface:
type CustomStruct struct {
    *BaseStruct
}

func (*c CustomStruct) Do() {}

// The user now instantiates the struct and needs to call a function

inst := CustomStruct{}
SomePackageFun(&inst)

// The below function receives the custom struct, and must call the base struct's method, but this fails

func SomePackageFunc(i Interface) {
    // declaring the function with Interface works but I can't call the methods of BaseStruct
    i.Stuff() // not recognized by the compiler
}
```

Comment: `func SomePackageFunc(a Interface)` . If `*CustomStruct` implements `Interface` you cann call SomePackageFunc with that. Note that you seem to try something inheritance-like: It won't work.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'll add more details to the question. My problem is that the function needs to call a method of the base struct in the user's object, but it throws exception

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, how and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to call a method on a variable of an interface type, you should add that method to the interface. Methods that come from embedded structs count for the purpose of satisfying interfaces. To call anything that isn't part of the interface, you have to assert to a concrete type (or a different interface type that has that method), which defeats the point.

Comment: So is there a better idiom to handle the scenario? I need the user to implement an interface of a predefined struct (that's because he's going to need to use some of the struct's methods). Then, an instance of his struct should be sent to a function, where the predefined methods should be called

Comment: @user1102018 Yes, again, add what you need to the interface :)